# Trouble with opening files or importing modules in VS code based on which folder I open vs code in

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

So if I open a folder in vs code that stores the files or modules I need to open or import, my code works fine, however if I open a folder higher in the directory, I get errors such as file not found.

Path: C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Programming\Python\30DaysPython\Day10

My .py file is in Day10, if I open VS code in that folder my program works, but if I open VS in 30DayPython, it doesn't work.

Why do I have to open vs in the folder that I am working on (containing my files), shouldn't it use the relative path of the file I am running and not where I open vs code from?

My code:

```
import os

email_txt = os.path.join('templates', 'email.txt')
content = ''

with open(email_txt, 'r') as f:
   enter code herecontent = f.read()
print(content.format(name='Joe'))
```

Image of opening vs code in 1 folder higher than the folder that contains the program and it doesn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your current working directory changed. When you open **30DaysPython** as current folder, you have to change the path code to

```
email_txt = os.path.join('Day10\\templates', 'email.txt')
```

Then the error should go away.

Comment: And does this same principle also apply to importing modules? For example, I have 2 files  in Day10 and want to import a function from one to the other file (and my current working directory is 30DaysPython), I'd have to do `from Day10.file1 import function` ?

Comment: No, it will throw an error `"No module named Day10"`. If my answer solved your original question, it's appreciated that you mark it.